# xarray.DataArray.roll method creates unwanted artifacts

Tags: python-xarray, cartopy

Recently I've been using xarray to load in a bunch of NetCDF files and to plot them using cartopy.

Today I've noticed an interesting thing. For my area of interest, I need to select the are from 20W to 40E longitude. By design, I can't do it in one method `KEdiff_mean.sel(lat=slice(-50, -10),lon=slice(-20,40))` like in NCL or other specific toolboxes for geospatial data, because lon starts from 0 to 0-360. It would return an empty data array if I called  `isel(lon=slice(-200,400)` instead (I work on 3600*1800 global grid), then I found this wonderful `DataArray.roll` method.

By rolling the DataArray along the lon dimension, I can then select the longitudes I want, crossing the 0 degree line
`KEdiff_mean.roll(lon=1800).isel(lon=slice(1600,2200)).sel(lat=slice(-50, -10))`

What's interesting is, when I plot it using `DataArray.plot`, I got this weird horizontal stripes over areas with no values. Either the roll method didn't work as I expected or I missed something, but the plot looks correct other than the stripes. Can anybody shed some lights? What's the recommended way to deal with this circular longitude selection? Maybe replace the longitude coordinate first from 0-360 to -180 to 180 by default? Thank you!

This is the correct plot: I plot globally then set extent of the plot
[image: Correct plot]

When roll is invoked:
[image: Roll before selection]

Comment: I suspect that manually wrapping the longitude values to 0-360 would indeed fix this -- that's certainly what I would try first.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I have any idea what is going on with the stripes on the land but one hack is use the mask from the original data by using [xr.where](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html) e.g for my wave data I use

```
hs = xr.open_dataarray('hs') # 2D file
mask = hs.where(hs > 0) # Keep points with data > 0, set others to NaN
new_var = new_var.where(mask > 0) # new_var should be 2D
```

Another hack (I know i'm not answering your questions) is to plot the data and add a feature over the land

```
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
# ...
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, facecolor='white')
```